# How to stop Angular 6 from sanitizing json payload

Tags: json, angular, angular6

I recently upgraded my angular project from version 4.2 to version 6. Everything works great, except I noticed that angular is now removing functions from my json payload when making a post request(this may be happening for other http options also but haven't checked them). Is there a way to disable this or a work around besides json.stringify?

Here's the json payload that I'm trying to post:

```
{
  name: "ghq_employeesTotal", 
  fieldMapping: ['item1'], 
  translation: ƒunction(val){ return val.toLowerCase()}
}
```

Here's the payload that I see being sent in the network tab:

```
{
  name: "ghq_employeesTotal", 
  fieldMapping: ['item1']
}
```

As you can see it's completely removing my translation property.

Here's my function sending the post request:

```
public publishConfig(config): Observable<any>{
  return this.http.post<any>(this.serviceURL + 'publish', config);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`ƒunction(val){ return val.toLowerCase()}` is not a valid *JSON* data type.

JSON only supports arrays, objects and primitive values.